# Mapping multiple address on googlemaps - javascript API and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I have a PHP variable that contains an array of addresses. I am using the Googlemaps v3 javascript API. I have a function that can geocode an address and place the marker but I am confused how to run that function for each address stored in the php variable.

Any ideas guys?

Edit: The geodecoding function is a javascript function.

Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
          var geocoder;
          var map;
          function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(58.813742, -98.789062);
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 4,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
          }

          //Change Address to Latlng and show on Map
          function codeAddress() {
            var address = "10 my house street, city, state";
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(14);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                });
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
            });
          }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop:

```
<?php

foreach ( $array_of_addresses as $address ) {

// Do Whatever

}

?>
```

Are you using the PHP library from Monte Ohrt? If not you should it's really good, you can download it here http://www.phpinsider.com/php/code/GoogleMapAPI/

Answer (score 0):

Define the JavaScript function once. Then, loop thru the PHP array and run the javascript function on each address. Here is an example:

```
function geocode() {
...
}

<?php
  foreach($arrAddress as $address) {
?>
    geocode('<?php echo $address; ?>');
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Allright. But, now I m facing another issue. I am now getting that the **geocoder is undefined**, even though I have defined geocode.

Check original post for the javascript function.

Comment: Ok. I got it. I am calling the geocoder function inside the body and I have set initalize() on body load. So, the geocoder function is being called before the initialize. So, now I need to find a way to call the geocoder function after the body initializes. Let's see what we I can do. Any thought guys?

Comment: Just drop the PHP code into the body after the codeAddress function.